# math question angle of elevation

Tags: trigonometry

[image]
A tree is $x$ meters high. The angle of elevation of its top from a point $P$ on the ground is 23 degrees. From another point $Q$, 10 meters from $P$ and in line with $P$ and the foot of the tree, the angle of elevation is 32 degrees. Find $x$.

[OP points out in the comments: if $QR=y$, then $\tan32=x/y$, so $y=x/\tan32$, and $\tan23=x/(10+y)$.]

Comment: Let QR = y. Can you use the two right angled triangles? Use them to set up two equations and solve them for y and x.

Comment: I am using tan32 = x/y +> y = x/tan32 and for x: tan 23 = x/10+y

Answer (score 4):

Let the length $PR$ be $y$. Then we have the following two equations:

In $\triangle PRS$, we have $\tan(23^\circ)=\frac{x}{y}$ $(1)$ and $\tan(32^\circ)=\frac{x}{y-10}$ $(2)$.

Solving for $y$ in equation $2$, we get $y=\frac{x}{\tan(32^\circ)}+10$. Plugging this into equation $1$ and solving [gives](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan%2823%29%3D%28x%29%2F%28%28x%29%2F%28tan32%29%2B10%29) $x\approx13.236$.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to get 
\begin{equation}
10 = \frac{x}{\tan 23^{o}}-\frac{x}{\tan 32^{o}}
\end{equation}
and then you can obtain that
\begin{equation}
x = \frac{10}{\frac{1}{\tan 23^{o}} - \frac{1}{\tan 32^{o}}} 
\end{equation}